# Can't remove padding on Vuetify expansion panel

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a text input field that gets shown at the click of a button.
When "KOMMENTAR HINZUFÜGEN" is clicked, it looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to get rid of the white padding below the black line; the text field should fill up the whole panel. I am trying to achieve this by setting the margins and paddings to 0 on the CSS, but no luck. Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel class="expansion-panel">
        <v-btn @click.prevent="showTextField = !showTextField" color="gray">Kommentar hinzufügen (optional)</v-btn>
        <v-text-field v-if="showTextField" v-model="comment" label="Kommentar" class="comment-field" ref="inputField" @click="$refs.inputField.focus()" autofocus></v-text-field>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .comment-field {
    width: 25em;
    height: 20em;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .expansion-panel {
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-text-field` is for single line.

You can use `v-textarea` with `hide-details: auto` to achieve your goal:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  const showTextField = ref(false)
  const comment = ref('')
</script>

<template>
  <v-expansion-panels>
    <v-expansion-panel>
      <v-btn @click.prevent="showTextField = !showTextField" color="grey">
        Kommentar hinzufügen (optional)
      </v-btn>
      <v-textarea
        v-if="showTextField"
        v-model="comment"
        label="Kommentar"
        hide-details="auto"
        autofocus
      ></v-textarea>
    </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-expansion-panels>
</template>
```

Playground:
https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNptkbFOwzAQhl/FeEmRSAKiE0orWFhY2QiD61xaC8e27EsoVH0zNl6Mi5vStEqW2Pf99v/f+W3Hg5f5k3NZ1wJ/4EWQXjlkAbB1TAuzXpQcQ8mXpWFMNc56ZDvmoWZ7VnvbsIQOJj2U1gQ6uLGfr7DFZwW6YoteOauFDnB90kjbNGBwoElCqMgPxmRDG4TGaYEQTYsuha0TJihrUvqDDrE+RQYQ0QoNe5RayY/MeejIkFq5jHd1Vig5ZdPWk3Dt4Wvo+vC9HEILzzbKfLf1788aDJtZh+QudGwvOufRepwE6X7hQZwu61JVX6Yp+Zg3tgJNkmFWY6jFKqL/RGO4URWkFaBQOpBGtGjHuN/XVrbhWFr2eY8Bj3Ol0tRgJ+r9UxT56L34/obfZ/Psbs6HxS1//wOrqsgW